# How to set style for features within atlas feature

Tags: qgis, symbology, atlas

I have a vector layer with property parcels, and another vector layer separating them into regions. I have the regions layer controlling an atlas. I would like to have only the parcels within the current region colored for each atlas page.

This is the rule I applied to the parcels:

```
 contains(  buffer(  @atlas_geometry ,5),  $geometry )
```

But it doesn't work. With that enabled, none of the features show. What am I doing wrong?

Qgis 2.14

Comment: Is 2.4 a typo? This expression will only work with QGIS 2.12 and above.

Comment: Yes I meant 2.14 sorry.

Comment: What about layer CRS? Are they both the same?

Comment: Both are in the same CRS.